# Plucker matrix as criterion if point is on a straight line.

Tags: matrices, geometry

I have read in a number of sources that:

1. A straight line in a 3D projective space, passing through two points a and b represented by column homogenous-coordinate vectors A and B, respectively, can be represented by a Plucker matrix

$$
PM=A\cdot B^T-B\cdot A^T
$$

where T means transpose, so the two terms are outer products (sorry, I don't yet know how to insert LaTeX here for prettier formulas).

2. For any point C in the same space, C is on our line iff PM*C=0

Now I have been trying to use this and I failed. Trying to find an error in my implementation, I finally resorted to checking the correctness of the formula itself, and started expanding it. For simplicity, I took C=A, as A is obviously on the line passing through A and B.

As you will see in the enclosed picture, in the final step I only expanded the first row - in fact, the first element of the PM*A vector, before I noticed that it does not reduce to zero.

What am I missing? Is my derivation faulty, or have I misunderstood the sources and distorted the criterion for C in line AB?

TIA for your help.
[image: My attempt to prove that PM*A=0]

Comment: I've modified the first bit of math for you as an example of how to insert LaTeX into your post.  You can also look at [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this isn’t working is that

> For any point $C$ in the same space, $C$ is on our line iff $PM\cdot C=0$

is not true. There are two different kinds of Plücker matrices and you appear to have confused them.

A line can be described as the join of two points $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$. This join can be encoded into the *Plücker matrix* $L=\mathbf A\mathbf B^T-\mathbf B\mathbf A^T$. (This can be interpreted as an instance of the technique known as “Plücker’s mu” or as a generalization of using the cross product of two points to represent a line in $\mathbb P^2$, but the derivation isn’t important here.) The point defined by the intersection of the line $L$ with the plane $\mathbf\pi$ is $\mathbf X=L\mathbf\pi$. This is zero iff $L$ is on $\mathbf\pi$. Multiplying a *point* by $L$, however, doesn’t do anything useful.

Alternatively, a line can be viewed as the meet of two planes $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q$, and there is a corresponding *dual* Plücker matrix $L^*=\mathbf P\mathbf Q^T-\mathbf Q\mathbf P^T$. This is the Plücker matrix that you want: the plane defined by the join of $L^*$ and the point $\mathbf X$ is $\mathbf\pi=L^*\mathbf X$, and $L^*\mathbf X=0$ iff $\mathbf X$ lies on $L^*$.

You can obtain $L^*$ from $L$ directly by a simple rewrite rule: $$l_{12}:l_{13}:l_{14}:l_{23}:l_{42}:l_{34} = l_{34}^*:l_{42}^*:l_{23}^*:l_{14}^*:l_{13}^*:l_{12}^*.$$ This correspondence rule can be described as follows: the indices of the corresponding original and dual components always include all of the numbers in $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so if the original is $ij$ then the dual indices are those of the set that are neither $i$ nor $j$, e.g., $12\mapsto34$. The rest of the matrix is filled in by skew-symmetry.

The null space of $L$ is spanned by the planes that contain the line, which suggests another method to compute $L^*$: compute a basis for the null space of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A&\mathbf B\end{bmatrix}^T$ and form $L^*$ from those two planes. Depending on what you’re doing, it’s often more efficient not to form the Plücker matrix explicitly, but instead to use the expression $\mathbf P\mathbf Q^T-\mathbf Q\mathbf P^T$ directly. Multiplying a point by this matrix then becomes two dot products, two scalar multiplications and a vector addition.

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm. Strange, few if any sources I have dug up mention there being two Plucker matrices. The Wikipedia article uses two different symbols (differentiated by a tilde above one of them), but doesn't explain what "the other" (tilde-embellished) one stands for.

Big huge enormous thanks :)